# Summary notification triggers sound effect

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

For testing purposes, I am sending 2 notifications and bundle them with a summary notification.
It works, but it causes 3 sound effects, implying that 3 separate notifications arrived. Is that intended behavior?

```
public void sendOnChannel1(View v) {
    String title1 = "Title 1";
    String title2 = "Title 2";
    String message1 = "Message 1";
    String message2 = "Message 2";

    Notification notification1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle(title1)
            .setContentText(message1)
            .setGroup("example_group")
            .build();

    Notification notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle(title2)
            .setContentText(message2)
            .setGroup("example_group")
            .build();

    Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle("summary content title")
            .setContentText("summary content text")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine(title2 + "  " + message2)
                    .addLine(title1 + "  " + message1)
                    .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                    .setSummaryText("user@example.com"))
            .setGroup("example_group")
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification1);
    notificationManager.notify(2, notification2);
    notificationManager.notify(3, summaryNotification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
To avoid having the summary make noise, we have to call `.setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_CHILDREN)` on it.